# how to move title over in iphone navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wish I could show you all a picture, but I have two buttons on the top right of my nav bar and a refresh button on the left. The title is in the middle, but the first two letters are getting overwritten by one of the buttons on the right.

How do I 'push' my title (or titleview - either one) so that the title moves over a bit? I want to move it around 60 pixels to the right.

The code below does what I want - BUT - for some reason now, the buttons do not work. The code for the buttons is identical to what I used before (and what used to work) the only difference is that it is now stored in the 'tools' toolbar/array.

**Any ideas on why my buttons are now deactivated?**

```
// creating the two center buttons in the navigation bar
// create a toolbar to have two buttons in the right
UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 44.01)];

// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];


// create a non-bordered button (ends up looking like a title)
UIBarButtonItem *bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photos" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain   target:self action:NULL];
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:NULL];
    [buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];


// create a spacer
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];


// create another button with a camera icon
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(showPhotoPicker)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];


// create a spacer
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];


// create another button with 'your photos'
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"your photos" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered   target:self action:@selector(showUserGallery)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the title's frame.
Meaning you can only hack;
1) add some white space at the beggining.
2) leave the title empty, and create a new label - place that label over your navBar.

Hope that helps, that's what I could think of right now.
~ Natanavra.

Answer (score 0):

Miriam, maybe the following code could help you.
Inside the viewDidLoad of my NavBarController I'm using it to put an image a little bit to the right of the center of my NavBar, instead of using the standart "title text". And the "Back Button" keeps working fine for me.

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [self navigationBar];
//inside the CGRectMake(), I can change the POSITION of my image, putting it anywhere.
UIView* imgContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 10, 50, 80)];

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[navBar viewWithTag:kSCNavBarImageTag];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar-bg.png"]];
[imageView setTag:kSCNavBarImageTag];

[imgContainer addSubview:imageView];
[self.navigationBar addSubview:imgContainer];

UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
[navBar setTintColor:myColor];

[imageView release];
```

I think you can use the same approach: create a "viewContainer" (instead imageContainer in my case) and put your title inside it.
I didn't try it with your scenario, but maybe it works.

Hope it helps you.
Regards.